# Update Value in GridView from another GridView using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I am working on a sample project. In which i am applying add to cart. Now in that i am having one `gridview` containing list of products with add to click button on each row. Now when i click on `Add to Cart` button of any product i get that value in another gridview. That is `gridview2`. If that product is already exist in the gridview2 then it will increase the quantity. And if it is not there then it will insert new row. And this is all happen on the each time click on `Add to cart` button of Gridview. Now i have done this using `RowCommand`. And getting successful result. But i want it to perform it using `jQuery`. I don't know how to perform it. So kindly help me to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with `jQuery` is not the best option as the `GridView` has `ViewState` and the items added through `jQuery` wont be added to `ViewState`. You can do it using **[UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)** using asp.net Ajax. You need to put both GridViews in same UpdatePanel, Your existing code on OnRowCommand will work as it is already working and **page wont refresh** and you will get ajax call. You can find many examples of using UpdatePanel with live demo over [**here**](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/updatepaneloverview.aspx).

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page each time.

Comment: Check the updated answer, I added link for understanding how UpdatePanel works in my answer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Comment: IMO this is most straight forward and suited way here, you can go through this article it also has examples with demonstrations, http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/updatepaneloverview.aspx

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/Samples/UpdatePanelWalkthrough2/cs/TriggersDeclarativeMarkupCS.aspx   You can check this exaple given on the site suggested by u..